# use Axios.post() to get values from local file

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios

I am working in React login. I am using `Axios.post('/api/users/login', value)` in one of my Component. Now I would like to store `userName` and `passWord` in a file and fetch values from a local file using `Axios`. I would like to have user login for a fixed username and password.

Is it possible to use Axios.post() to get values from local file ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to read it from a json file locally and upload it as login?

Comment: Thanks @AaminKhan. I would like to store `userName` & `passWord` in a text file  and user will login using that `userName` & `passWord`.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried, it doesn't work, but I think you should try to use the `fs` native module of node.js, that can access to the File System.

Comment: Thanks @Wassel. Do you have any tutorial on that ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp It seems to be a good tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native javascript `FileReader` to read it in the browser and then process/manipulate according to your need. In this case the file contents is like below `credentials.txt`

```
userName: email@domain.com
passWord: yourpassword
```

JSX

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.openFile.bind(this)} />
```

onChange Handler

```
openFile(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const arr = reader.result.split(/\r?\n/);
      this.login({
        userName: arr[0].split(":")[1],
        passWord: arr[1].split(":")[1]
      });
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
}
```

The login method

```
login(loginObj) {
    // make api calls
    axios.post("/api/users/login", loginObj).then(resp => {
      // do your stuff
    });
  }
```

Code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-feynman-vjtxo

Cheers!!